# Getting pst-poker to work

Tags: pstricks

I need help with the pst-poker package included in texlive. I verified that everything is installed, but if I try to run

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poker}
\begin{document}
\As
\end{document}
```

I get the "Undefined control sequence. \As" error.

Note that if I try to load the package using "\usepackage{poker2}" as instructed in the documentation, it tells me "File `poker2.sty' not found. \begin". I guess the name of the package has simply changed and the documentation hasn't been updated.

Now, if I make it run despite the error, I get this messed up output:

[image]

so clearly the package exists and is detected, but there's a weird bug.

Edit: Alright, compiling with latex/dvips/ps2pdf works. xelatex works as well, and also seems to work with documents that give me errors with latex in dvi mode, and even works through latexmk!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your MWE runs through without any problem on my TeXLive 2017 installation, which is up-to-date according to my package manager.

Comment: `latexmk` isn't smart enough to detect that you need to compile with `latex+dvips` instead of `pdflatex`.  So you need to tell TeX Studio to compile it that way.

Comment: You also can compile with `pdflatex` if  add `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` (*after* pstricks) and add the option `--enable-write18` to pdflatex switches if you're under MiKTeX, or `-shell-escape` for TeX Live or MacTeX.

Comment: @Bernard it indeed runs, but if I use latexmk and pass --shell-escape, it keeps making passes and tells me the file is not stable.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that. As I dont use latexmk, I  have no idea whether it is a configuration problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence or `xelatex`.

### Example 1

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-poker}
\begin{document}
\crdAs
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Example 2

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-poker}
\begin{document}
\Ah
\Ad
\Ac
\As
\crdAh
\crdAd
\crdAc
\crdAs
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to explain  the source of the error, for the OP, since the problem is not with the MWE provided, so new examples will yield the same error if not compiled with the right engine.

Comment: Alright, compiling with latex/dvips/ps2pdf works. xelatex runs forever without returning any output... Unfortunately, a bunch of other documents I work with won't compile when trying to generate a dvi (I get a bunch of "not allowed in DVI mode"), so I'm stuck if I try to add a poker card on those documents...

Comment: @Alexbib: there should be no problem with xelatex. Does it hang with your original example?

Comment: @Herbert I was mistaken, lualatex is the one that hangs, xelatex runs properly.

Comment: For `lualatex` you need package `auto-pst-pdf-lua`

Answer (score 6):

Using `lualatex --shell-escape <file>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poker}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf-lua}

\begin{document}
\begin{postscript}
\As \crdAs
\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Package [auto-pst-pdf-lua](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/auto-pst-pdf-lua)